# how to find out the url request from a socket?

Tags: java, sockets

Hi i am running a server socket created in java that accepts requests from a client that uses HTTP url to connect and send web requests.

client does this:

```
URLconnection.opeonConnection(new Url(www.hello.com/hi));
```

on my server socket it retrieves a Socket object.

is it possible to retrieve the url www.hello.com/hi url that was passed to this socket conection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, by parsing the client's HTTP headers:

You can get the "/hi" portion with some work.  The URL Connection class will use the HTTP protocol to submit some HTTP headers, along with a GET request as "GET /hi  HTTP/1.1".   The "/hi" portion comes from the URL.

The "www.hello.com" part might be more difficult.   The browser will provide the host and port (if port is given) portion of the URL in a "Host: " header.  It's likely that your networking infrastructure may contain proxies or load balancers that forward the request on to the final backend server, and if the proxies aren't configured correctly, they won't maintain the original host header.   Try it yourself, and talk to your network administrators if it's not working as you expect.

If you want to see what the URL connection class will send to your server you can get an idea by pointing your browser to this URL: http://request.urih.com/.  The "request header: raw source" section shows you the HTTP headers sent by an HTTP client (your browser).

The ["HTTP Headers for Dummies"](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/) web page is also a good introduction to HTTP headers

Comment: Cheers.this could work. I just need to parse the headers to get the correct URL. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to get the `String` but not the way you likely want it.

You can implement a HTTP-Server (see [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)). But it is likely that you don't want this.

You can also use a `Servlet` container like Tomcat or Jetty and write a `Servlet` to use HTTP. With this the `Servlet` container does all the protocol and you can concentrate on doing the business logic.

Comment: cheers. unfortunatly i have to build this all from the ground up.

Comment: @jonney I don't understand why you have to do this. It will be very, very hard to create a HTTP server that you can use. A `Servlet` container will be much easier and I don't understand why you can't use one.

Answer (score 1):

As you state you're building a proxy, you're already asking the wrong question.

An HTTP proxy only has to deal with one command: the CONNECT command. You just have to:

1. Read this one line from the client.
2. Connect to the target indicated in the command.
3. Reply with success or failure.
4. If success, start copying bytes in both directions.

But I don't know why you're even implementing an HTTP proxy when there are dozens of free working ones already in existence.

Comment: Is there a proxy that gets raw http data instead of the proxy handling it for u? i need the raw data as the task at hand is to pass the http request in a different format/protocol

Answer (score -3):

In in the interface Socket there is getRemoteSocketAddress(). It returns a SocketAddress, and if the implementation of SocketAddress is InetSocketAddress, try to call getHostString().

```
SocketAddress address =yourSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().
String address=((InetSocketAddress)address).getHostString();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That won't retrieve a URL, just an IP address. What if we need the URL with querystring info?

Comment: can't you retrieve any instance of ServletRequest? if you have a instance of ServletRequest you can access to the values of the request parameters  using the methods  getParameterMap() , getParameterValues() or getParameter()

Comment: @Amalgovinus You should have read the documentation of InetSocketAddress at http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#getHostString()  "Returns the hostname, or the String form of the address if it doesn't have a hostname (it was created using a literal). This has the benefit of not attemptimg a reverse lookup." Which means that it returns an IP address if the hostname has not been mapped :)